# Reverting to original element ID

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have li blocks which `onclick` will change class ID as follows:

```
onclick = "document.getElementById('procblock1').id = 'procblock1Clicked';"
       "document.getElementById('procblock2Clicked').id = 'procblock2';"
       "document.getElementById('procblock3Clicked').id = 'procblock3';"
       "document.getElementById('procblock4Clicked').id = 'procblock4';"
```

The line     `document.getElementById('procblock2Clicked').id = 'procblock2';` should revert any clicked elements (blocks) back to their original ID names.

The code works for changing the original id to the clicked id but doesn't have any effect in reverting previously clicked  to the original as per lines 2,3 & 4.

I have searched hard for similar questions but can find nothing that covers this specific issue.

Comment: All i see is some invalid javascript, can you post the real code you wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matthias - I acted upon your advice and came up with a very simplified jquery solution :

```
`$(function() { 
    $(".showinfo").click(function() { //using class instead of ID
    $(".showinfo").removeClass("clicked"); //Remove all existing clicks
    $(this).addClass("clicked"); //add the class to the clicked element }); 
});`
```

Posted solution in case anyone else has same query. Your help was appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this really is part of the code you're using lines 2-4 won't work; onclick will only handle the first line. You should wrap it as a function to be called onclick, like onclick = "doStuff()"  and add a   `function doStuff ()  {/* your code here */}`. But that's just guessing as you only provide some part of the code in question.

In addition would be good to know what you want to achieve - in case you want to mark clicked elements, it would be a cleaner approach to add a class, e.g. "clicked" or "active", that you simply remove later on instead of changing ids.

Comment: Thanks Matthias - I do have it in a function but was showing the basics in case it was something obvious. I have a jsfiddle trying it out at http://jsfiddle.net/MikeMac67/062rkq93/

Comment: @MikeMcMonagle Ok, I see now.. if it's really only setting the css it's easier to adjust it to use classes for the active element. If you would consider to use some javascript-library like jQuery this would be even more easier with a toggle-function, but it's also possible to clean up the code you provided a bit.

Comment: Thanks Matthias. The click performs other functions where toggle would be impractical but I think I shall try the route of appending the a class. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @MikeMcMonagle Just noticed your new answer. Glad to be of help by pointing in the right direction and that you were able to fix it on your own.